# Line-Wrap issue for highlighted span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this highlighted span in which you can type text

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sewpjeta/1/)

You can click on the white area and start typing. Now when you type and you reach the and I would like it to wrap.

The HTML is not very special:

```
<div>
  Complete the story:<br>
  Once upon a time there was <span></span>. And they all die :)
</div>

<input>
```

To make the typing possible I use a hidden (not hidden in the demo) input field. Anyway, now when you start typing and you reach the end of the line it should wrap as follows:

[image]

I've tried things like `word-wrap:break-word;` but that didn't work very well. Is something like this even possible ?

Comment: Why not do something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/sewpjeta/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't wrap text in an `input`. You could use a `textarea` instead. You will have to adjust your CSS for the size of the span to grow as the text spans multiple lines, by changing the `height` to `min-height`:

```
   min-height: 20px;
```

See this fiddle for working version: https://jsfiddle.net/3L4bazg6/7/

I've also removed some of the styling in your span rule to get the wrap effect you are looking for.

[image]

Here's another fiddle that hides the textarea completely: https://jsfiddle.net/3L4bazg6/10/

And, here's a fiddle that does away with the `textarea` and the JavaScript completely and just uses `contenteditable`:" https://jsfiddle.net/3L4bazg6/17/

Answer (score 0):

Refering to your js fiddle

- Change `display: inline-flex;` to `display: inline;`
- Remove `height: 20px;`
- Add `line-height`

here is your updated JSfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sewpjeta/9/

Comment: This moves the entire span to a new line as soon as just a part of it doesn't fit on the old line. Also, it doesn't increase the height of the span as the text becomes more than one line long.

Comment: I forgot to update the JSfiddle link, its updated now you can see the result there.